# Hbase performance issues while loading 45 GB data file

Tags: hbase

Hbase performance issues

Scenario1 ->
I am loading the data into hbase table through pig loader and the data file approx 45GB and there are 6 processes which load the data into 6 different hbase tables. Some of the processes complete in 6-7 hours and other processes take 18 hours. Why this abnormal behavior I am facing in hbase I mean to say same amount of data load in just 6-7 hours and sometime it takes more than 18 hours.

Scenario 2-->
And after that I implement the Hashing to load the data into hbase but still it is taking much time to load the data into hbase. I tested 1 process at a time and it took approx 7 hours.

Can anyone help me on this how to improve the performance of Hbase loading.

Thanks in Advnace.
Regards
Amit

Comment: Can anyone comment on this?

Comment: Did you pre-Split the tables according to your region servers.?? provide as much heap to HBase regions and pre split to avoid Hot spotting.

Comment: may you add the num of your regionservers and the hardware infos

Comment: @karthik  Thanks for your response , We have not done pre splitting on hbase table and when I checked then it's showing 10GiB Default value Could you please help us how to split on the above info.